# How can I answer calls with desktop Skype instead of Windows 8 Skype?

Tags: windows-8, skype

How can I answer calls with desktop Skype instead of Windows 8 Skype? Do I need to uninstall Windows 8 Skype?

Answer (score 1):

When you have an income call and both of desktop and Windows 8 Skype app installed, then you will get an income call from both of them. You just need to answer on the desktop Skype client.

If you want to get calls only the destop app then you need to uninstall the Windows 8 Skype app because you can't log out since the Windows 8 app use your built in Microsoft (Live) account. You could only sing out in the PC settings but then all of the app whats use it will log out (skydrive, office, onenote etc..)

**To uninstall the Windows 8 skype**

1. Right click on the skype title on the Start Screen
2. Choose Uninstall from the menu which came up on the bottom of the screen.

**Download and install Desktop skype**

1. Go to http://www.skype.com/hu/download-skype/skype-for-windows/downloading/
2. Start the downloaded installer.
3. Start Skype, login and you could use the skype on desktop

Answer (score -1):

You have to login through the desktop skype. But this won't go for long, they're removing the desktop skype in a month (i guess) so that means we will all use the "app" kind of skype.